# How to create a grid layout that adapte based on the content height?

Tags: css, grid

I would like to create a grid of two column, and the number of row will depends on the content of each elements.

For example, the first child could be a list of comments, and depending on the product the number of comments will change, so the height too.

I think the css grid could help, but fow now I haven't found a soulution here is what I have. For the purpose of the snippets I have define an height for the blocks inside the css, but in reality it will vary depending on the content.

I've seen the `grid-auto-flow` that seems to be close to what I want but I'm not sure how to use it.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  padding: 2em;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}
.wrapper > div {
  border: red solid 2px;
}


.wrapper > div:nth-child(1) {
height:150px; // I set the height to 150px, but it could be less or more, depends on the content
}

.wrapper > div:nth-child(6) {
height:100px; // I set the height to 100px, but it could be less or more, depends on the content
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 2</div>
  <div>Child 3</div>
  <div>Child 4</div>
  <div>Child 5</div>
  <div>Child 6</div>
  <div>Child 7</div>
</div>
```

I would like something that can adapt based on the content heigh, for exemple:
[image]

Comment: the height of a div automatically adjusts to its content, so if you dont mind placing two wrapper divs side by side that contain the children, you won't even need CSS for this. Or am I missing somthing here?

Comment: @MatthiasSeifert I'm not sure to understand,you mean placing all the div without the display grid on the parent ? but then they wont be on two colums ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention, that you might want to use something like flexbox to place the left and right column side by side. So I might correct me and say, you won't need a lot of CSS for this ;) Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/8e65c0b3/1/

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but in my case, all child divs depends on their content, and on one page it could be ok, but on an other where the content would be bigger, the colums are not "equals".  For example: https://jsfiddle.net/sfprmaL1/ The last "your boat" is far at the bottom and i would need to scroll, so instead it would be better to have this div on the left

Comment: My problem is that sometimes the big divs will be on the right, and sometimes on the left, it all depends on the content that is typed by the users

Comment: So you want to distribute the children as equal as possible to the left and the right? Then yes, my solution would be "too simple" ;)

Comment: Yes, I would like to have tow colums that would be as equals as possible

Comment: Does css property columns: 2 help?

Comment: @AHaworth It's seems to be better, but now it's splitting the divs. And when you disable this, the colums are no longer equals, see https://jsfiddle.net/bh90r6j7/2/

Comment: Yes, so not what you want I guess.